# Build an example with Twilio of a call from phone A to phone B

Tags: java, twilio

Does anyone know if in **Twilio** it is possible to mount an application with the following requirements?:

1. From an 'A' telephone, that of the telemarketer or sender, an 'X' telephone of the receiver indicated from the application will be called.
2. The application must be able to intercept if the phone 'X':

   2.1. Does not exist.

   2.2. It exists but communicates.

   2.3. It exists, does not communicate but does not pick up.

   2.4. It exists, does not communicate, picks up and the conversation takes place.
3. If the conversation occurs, detect when it ends.
4. The conversation is recorded.
5. Asynchronously, make a request to Twilio to recover the recording and delete it.

I have been seeing the documentation on their website and I have some doubts:

1. Can it be done from a standalone Java application? Or does it have to be web?.
2. The telephone A sender, how should it be configured from Twilio? (I'm getting involved with the concepts of verified phone, purchased phone, 'webhook', etc).

Can someone point me to an example that does that? I am a bit lost.

Comment: Is your application on the phones ? If yes does both the phones have the application ?

Comment: No, this is not the case. It is intended to be a Java Standalone application that put in communication Phone A (internal of the organization) to Phone 1, Phone 2,... Phone N (externals to the company).

Answer (score 1):

I have used twilio a long time ago, but from what I remember :

1. **You can** record a conversation but I don't think it is free to do so (You have limited storage and need to pay if you want more, I will let you check that one).
2. Twilio **will** detect when the conversation ends and stop both call.
3. You must be able to recover your recording from a java application.
4. I don't know if you can know all the points from your part 2. there might be some return code from Twilio API that could tell you that but I'm usure about that.
5. Your application will need to use VoIP and have webhooks configured so I'm pretty sure you will need a web app with a **certified ssl certificate** not a **self-signed one** otherwise Twilio will not accept the latter and will not let you send messages or calls. For free **certified ssl certifcate** you can check [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).
6. You can check the the [Twilio API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api), I'm pretty sure you will find a lot more information in there. Regarding your points you might want to focus on the [Voice API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api) and the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api)

Comment: Thnk Philippe, I dont mind if we have to pay for the recorded conversations or other concepts. I am just trying to get to a code example that serves me as a base from start. The examples I have found in the Twilio app to send an SMS and to do a call and reproduce a stored message dont serves for me.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot help you more than that. I don't have the application I created anymore and I followed the Twilio documentation to develop it anyway.